# Criteria joining two tables using more than one parameter

Tags: java, database, hibernate, join, criteria

I have two tables which are related:

```
+-----------+           +----------+
|   First   |  *     1  |  Second  |
+-----------+ --------- +----------+
| fk_Second |           | id       |
| version   |           | ...      |
| ...       |           | y        |
| x         |           +----------+
+-----------+
```

Hibernate has a `ManyToOne` definition from `First` to `Second`. The `{fk_Second, version}` is a `composite-id` of the `First` table (although I don't think it's relevant in this case).

I am trying to write Criteria call, which in SQL would look like as:

```
SELECT * FROM First WHERE 
   First.fk_Second = Second.id AND 
   First.x = Second.y
```

I'm finding trouble in generating the last bit - the extra join condition.

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(First.class);
   .createCriteria("second", "join_between_first_and_second")
   .add(Restrictions.eqProperty("y", "x")   // <- fails: "x" is not found
```

I can not use HQL queries in this situation. Is there any way writing this differently? Can this be written avoiding subquery/`DetachedCriteria`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(First.class, "first");
c.createAlias("first.second", "theSecond");
c.add(Restrictions.eqProperty("first.x", "theSecond.y");
```

If you don't prepend an alias to your property, the property is considered part of the root entity of the criteria (First in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Try HQL **'With'** clause..

```
SELECT f.* FROM First f left join Second s ON f.fk_Second = s.id with f.x = s.y;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already have this written in HQL and I need to migrate to Criteria. I have mentioned in my question that I don't need HQL solution.